# Use np.where to check if a column string exists in another list column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large DataFrame with 100 million records, I am trying to optimize the run time by using `numpy`.

Sample data:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'item' : ['beauty', 'beauty', 'shoe','shoe','handbag'],
                   'mylist' : [['beauty','something'], ['shoe', 'something', 'else'], ['shoe', 'else','some'], ['else'], ['some', 'thing', 'else']]})


dat

    ID  item    mylist
0   1   beauty  [beauty, something]
1   2   beauty  [shoe, something, else]
2   3   shoe    [shoe, else, some]
3   4   shoe    [else]
4   5   handbag [some, thing, else]
```

I am trying to filter those rows where `item` column's string exists in `mylist` column using:

```
dat[np.where(dat['item'].isin(dat['mylist']), True, False)]
```

But I am not getting any output and all of above values as `False`.
I could get the required results using:

```
dat[dat.apply(lambda row : row['item'] in row['mylist'], axis = 1)]

    ID  item    mylist
0   1   beauty  [beauty, something]
2   3   shoe    [shoe, else, some]
```

But as `numpy` operations are faster, I am trying to use `np.where`. Could someone please let me know who to fix the code?

Comment: There's no way to vectorise this operation with numpy. Nested lists in a column is not _really_ the best use case for pandas. A comprehension with zip ([like here](/a/69771593/15497888)) is probably the best option, but it's still going to be rather slow at that scale. If possible restructuring the data would be a better long-term solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't vectorize easily with Series of lists, you can use a list comprehension to be a bit faster than `apply`:

```
out = dat.loc[[item in l for item,l in zip(dat['item'], dat['mylist'])]]
```

A vectorial solution would be:

```
out = dat.loc[dat.explode('mylist').eval('item == mylist').groupby(level=0).any()]

# or
out = dat.explode('mylist').query('item == mylist').groupby(level=0).first()

# or, if you are sure that there is at most 1 match
out = dat.explode('mylist').query('item == mylist')
```

But the `explode` step might be a bottleneck. You must try with your real data.

output:

```
   ID    item               mylist
0   1  beauty  [beauty, something]
2   3    shoe   [shoe, else, some]
```

##### timing

I ran a quick test on 100k rows (using `df = pd.concat([dat]*20000, ignore_index=True)`)

- the list comprehension is the fastest (~20ms)
- explode approaches are between 60-90ms (explode itself requiring 40ms)
- apply is by far the slowest (almost 600ms)

Comment: Thanks, will test for speed, but for my understanding Is `numpy` vectorization not possible with list columns?

Comment: I added a vectorial alternative, but it might not be faster (requires to explode, compare, group, aggregate), you can try and let me know

Comment: quick test on 100k rows, the list comprehension is the fastest (~20ms), the `explode` approaches are between 60-90ms (`explode` itself requiring 40ms), and `apply` is by far the slowest (almost 600ms)